# How to access Xml Node with name formed only by numbers using C# and XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

consider this following XML generated by one tool:

```
<root>
    <GameToVideoMap>
        <200000001120460>
            <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
            <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
            <Title>Text</Title>
        </200000001120460>
        <13131>
            <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
            <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
            <Title>Text</Title>
        </13131>
        <2>
            <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
            <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
            <Title>Text</Title>
        </2>
    </GameToVideoMap>
</root>
```

Where **GameToVideoMap** is a *dictionary*. I want to access the URLs using a XPath string generated by some function. So I would have the following command:

```
string path = "/root[1]/GameToVideoMap[1]/200000001120460[1]/VideoThumbnailUrl[1]";
XmlNode targetNode = targetDoc.SelectSingleNode(path);
```

The problem is that the **SelectSingleNode** raises an exception *"Expression must evaluate to a node-set."*. If I use the path only as:

```
string path = "/root[1]/GameToVideoMap[1]";
```

Then if works nicely and I can see that it has a child node named "200000001120460" on the debug mode on Visual Studio like it is on the XML document. So I think that my problem is that the node's number is formed only by digits. Is there a way to escape the name of the node to be able to use the XPath query for a XML in that format? Or am I doing something wrong that I didn't notice. Thanks for the time.

Comment: That input is not XML as a name is not allowed to start with a digit, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar. So I don't think you can parse that input with any XML parser and then use XPath against it.

Comment: Answer question a few week ago to use regex to fix this type problem.  See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232902/xml-file-replacing-numeric-tag-names-with-a-valid-ones/33234880#33234880

Comment: That's a terrible XML format.  Elements should not have unique names, creating an element node with a unique attribute (see the <elem val='111'> example below is a much better, more flexible, easier to program solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for the warning about the XML format guys, I will use a solution based on JSON instead of XML, but I was thinking in some solution like Hamed suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a valid XML so I'm suggesting using the regular expressions.
You can convert your Text to XML by either converting the The numberic node names to be attributes

```
<root>
<GameToVideoMap>
    <elem val='200000001120460'>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </elem>
    <elem val='13131'>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </elem>
    <elem val='2'>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </elem>
</GameToVideoMap>
```

**Or**

Also you can just suffix them with a character like

```
<root>
<GameToVideoMap>
    <m200000001120460>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </m200000001120460>
    <m13131>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </m13131>
    <m2>
        <VideoThumbnailUrl>URL Text</VideoThumbnailUrl>
        <VideoUrl>Text</VideoUrl>
        <Title>Text</Title>
    </m2>
</GameToVideoMap>
```

If you had take the decision to make your data into a valid XML, you can use the XPath.

I hope this could help.